# How to use MinGW's gcc compiler when installing Python package using Pip?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, pip, distutils

I configured MinGW and distutils so now I can compile extensions using this command:

```
setup.py install
```

MinGW's gcc compiler will be used and package will be installed. For that I installed MinGW and [created distutils.cfg](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#location-and-names-of-config-files) file with following content:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

It's cool but now I'd like to use all pip benefits. Is there a way to use the same MinGW's gcc compiler in pip? So that when I run this:

```
pip install <package name>
```

pip will use MinGW's gcc compiler and compile C code if needed?

Currently I get this error: `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. Seems pip doesn't know that I have gcc compiler. How can I configure pip to use gcc compiler?

Comment: Another tip: make sure that the file is called *distutils.cfg* and not *distutils.cfg.txt*.  Sometimes Windows likes to add the *.txt* extension when you make a new text file.

Answer (score 108):

- install MinGW with C++ Compiler option checked
- add `C:\MinGW\bin` to your PATH
- in `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils`, create a file `distutils.cfg` and add these lines:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

Comment: The distutils.cfg file creation is what solved this for me - I was trying to install a package with pip and got the dreaded "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that you should change this for the python in your virtualenv if you use one.

Comment: Thanks. Still tedious. If only Pip had a `--compiler` option https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/18 please weigh in

Comment: Just a note, if you are using virtualenv, you have a separate distutils.cfg to change -- this was my problem!

Comment: I have windows 8.1 on a 64 bit computer. After attempting the above I received the error : `error: You should not use mingw32 for gcc >= 4.6.0. Use mingw64 instead, e.g.:python setup.py build_ext -c mingw64`
I altered the `[build]` entry in the distutils.cfg file to read `compiler=mingw32` and had success.

Answer (score 23):

Even though configuration file solves this problem, it's not always an option. I had the same issue for my command line installation process and I was not able to change config files on all the machines and python distributions.

This is my solution:

For **mingw32** and packages, which use VC++ as default:

```
pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option --compiler=mingw32 <package_zip>
```

For **Visual C++** on WinPython, which uses mingw32 as default:

```
pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option --compiler=msvc <package_zip>
```

Comment: Where can we get the <package_zip> ? Is it the whl file?

Comment: <package_zip> is a zipped pip package with sources inside, which require compilation. You can download many from https://pypi.org/