# vcvarsall.bat with Python 2.7 cannot use pip to install fabric

Tags: python, pip

I've searched SO regarding this question, and the only information is regarding Python 2.6.

The apparent fix as outlined here for example: [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) does not seem to work with Python 2.7

I am trying to install fabric utilizing the command `pip install fabric` and am getting a long list of errors ending with `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

If anyone could advise on a fix, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making sure it's in PATH?

Comment: Yes - I have C:\MinGW\bin; in my PATH..

Comment: That's a Visual Studio batch file, iirc. Do you have VC installed and in the path or are you going with the full open source solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your distutils.cfg file might not be in the right place.  Take a look at the fix outlined here: [pip mingw compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/pip-mingw-compile)?  If that doesn't help, [search StackOverflow for vcvarsall](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vcvarsall) and you'll find other discussions.

Answer (score 0):

you could check up the following that might be helpful:

http://shop.wickeddevice.com/2013/12/11/windows-7-python-virtualenv-and-the-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-error/