# Installing Pandas for Python 2.7 64 bit - Error unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python-2.7, windows-8, numpy, pandas, enthought

I am trying to install the pandas module. I tried an installer before but when importing I got some cryptic errors. I read that using pip is the recommended way to install packages.

When I use `pip install pandas` it manages to install pandas, dateultils and another package but when it arrives to numpy it exits with the error `"Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"`.

Of course, I searched for this problem which seems to be very common. However, none of the solution listed (several and not very clear/consistent worked). I have a Visual Studio 8 folder in program files. I also installed VS 2012 express which added a Visual Studio 11 folder. The only vcvarsall.bat that I found is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC`.

I added that folder to the path to no avail. I also installed mingw and added `c:mingw/bin` to the path. Nothing. I have a distutils.cfg with the `compiler=mingw32` set already. I did not create it or modified it. It was already there. It puzzles me because my python dist and all modules should be 64 bit. I have a EPD python built on this laptop. I run Win8 that I read seems to be harder to manage.

There seem to be several ways but none is exactly clear and the above did not work for me at all.

Please, if you know how to help, write a step-by-step way to and explain the rationale behind it. For example, in other threads, people suggest to add this variable or another one, or this to the path, or that, and it's not clear why and it seems to depend on a particular system. I am not sure what I should do indeed.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to understand your problem. Is your python distribution EPD or one that you downloaded manually? With EPD or Canopy, both numpy and pandas are installed by default, even in the free version.

Comment: As previous comment said, if you are using Enthought Python then you don't need to build pandas as it is already pre-built. But for building any C extensions that are not pre-built (or for building them on another python distribution) you will actually need Visual Studio 2008 installed, as that is what was used to build python 2.7 pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Try running it from the Visual C command shell, after setting the environment as described in the [Cython wiki](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows). You would probably be better off, if all you want is to compile Python extensions, to install the SDK listed in that link, rather than a newer version of Visual Studio. That should take care of your missing `vcvarsall.bat`, but compiling numpy under windows is a hard task, better left to Christoph Gohlke: get the binaries for numpy and pandas from [his repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), its the easiest way.

Comment: So, yes, I installed EPD 7.3-2 around last Spring. Apparently, it did not have pandas as the import didn't work. I tried to install it but didn't work as described. 

Maybe re-installing everything is the easiest option; do you think so?

Comment: BTW, of course I have numpy with EPD but as mentioned in the question, I was trying to use pip to install pandas and it goes through the step of installing numpy anyway. Maybe a newer version (update)? I am not sure, but it tries even if I have one and it fails as detailed above. Also, if I try to import pandas it gives errors, sometime different (!!), for example:

ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

or others related to hashtable...

Comment: The error mentioned above (which is different from some other ones I got before trying pip) seems to be related to a 32/64 bit incompatibility maybe? I downloaded EPD 64bit anyway... and I guess pip would install the 64bit version of pandas, too. Otherwise, could that be the problem anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install numpy using

> easy_install numpy

I had the same problem using pip, until I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658092/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-using-python-3-3-in-windows-8) article. It works!

Comment: This didn't work for me and I had the same vcvarsall-bat error.

Comment: `easy_install pandas` worked for me.  When `pip install pandas` wouldn't work for some reason.