# installing python module on windows 8

Tags: python

I am doing a project in python where I have a very large dataset where I have to do a fisher exact test. This must be done 600,000,000 times so efficiency is quite important. However, with the scipy package this takes 50 hours, but I have read that https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fisher/ should be much faster. But I don't understand how to get it installed in Windows 8.

I have tried using: python setup.py install, this gives the error:

```
D:\Programmer\Python\Scripts\fisher-0.1.4>python setup.py install

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'fisher/cfisher' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

what is wrong?

Comment: You asked a [question with the same title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288172/installing-a-python-module-on-windows-8) an hour ago that you deleted.  Care to explain?

Comment: Try `pip install fisher`.

Comment: Note that you'll need Cython and a C compiler to build the package from source.

Comment: I have tried pip install fisher also.
It gives another error, but I want paste it all into here since its quite long, but the last 3 lines is:
Cannot export initfisher/cfisher: symbol not defined

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: You need a C compiler. VC++, or mingw, cygwin, whatever works for you. That's what the error is about.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

Type into the Command Prompt window:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Python27\
```

And hit enter.

Use the complete path to the folder using CD.

eg: `cd c:\Users\fisher-0.1.4`

Then type `python setup.py install`

Comment: How is this different than what the OP has already tried (as shown)?

Comment: I don't think he has invoked the interpreter.

Comment: The OP has entered `python setup.py install`, and the first lines of output show that `setup.py` is indeed being run correctly. It's only at the stage where the C extension is being built (judging from the name) that things go wrong.

Comment: I have python installed at D:\Programmer\Python
I guess it shouldnt be exactly set path=%path%;C:\Python27\ then?
I havent tried this before, so I need it to be absolutely clear for me to know what to do

Comment: Then there might be a chance that he has not installed VC++.

Comment: @user3752939 then change it to D drive.

Comment: does 27 refer to python 2.7? Since I have 3.3
Also, VC++ 2012 is installed

Comment: Yes.That is for 2.7. Instead of python27 type the folder name for 3.3

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. I have written path=%path%;D:programmer\Python\ (this is where python is installed) and then python setup.py install. Still with the same error. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Check out the first answer about easy_install here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: and it's not `path=` it's `set path=`

Comment: Sorry typo, I did use set path. easy_install gives another error which I wont copy/paste here since it is very long