# unable to find file vcvarsall.bat installing pysam

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.4

I have python 3.4 and windows 7 x86.

After trying to install `pysam` through command line using pip install, it always gives me an error `unable to find file vcvarsall.bat`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You got visual studio 2010?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Visual Studio 8 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2005 and 2008 and 2010.

Comment: This has to be the most common error encountered when installing python modules on Windows platforms. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1) and do read the comments (they're important here). Also very good is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23397327/2476444).

Comment: I have tried everything and still nothing.
I will just do my own code.
Thanks