# Python, failed to install. Exit code: 1 windows 10

Tags: python, pip, package

So, I have going over this back and forth, I tried several of the solutions on this forum, none worked.

I have pip3 installed, Python 3.4, Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Now whenever I run the installing for a new module manually or through pip3 I get the following error:

Say I use the cmdline as such:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

I get :

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\ariel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -c 
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ariel
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-41rz6w_o\\numpy\\setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read()
.replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
C:\Users\Ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vuq3ap0m-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1
in C:\Users\Ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-41rz6w_o\numpy
```

If I download it and run it from the folder

```
 setup.py install
```

I get

```
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Please help, considering to just use linux with python... less issues

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @Jaco I tried `easy_install`, I still get `error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: You need to install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: @Jaco same problem, that didn't seem to help

Comment: Look [here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469210-Windows-Unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-cython-other-c-extensions-).

Comment: Why not install Anaconda Python from continuum.io? I've installed it successfully on win7 and win8.1, and use the VS15 IDE with it using Python Tools for Visual Studio. Plus, the Conda package and environment manager is awesome.

Comment: @Jim thanks your solution worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on @Jim answers in the comment section, basically make sure that you have the C++ compiler **and** windows SDK installed!

My problem was that when I installed Visual Studio, I did not select the windows SDK.