# "pip install nexmo" fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, vonage

I want to integrate [nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) into my Python product, so that I can send SMS. On my localhost (Python 3.6.1), [using this](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-python#installation), I have installed it easily by

> pip intall nexmo

However now I want to move everything to the server and the

> pip intall nexmo

fails:[image]

Edit: I also tried the "easy_install", as indicated in this other post on stackoverflow: "[pip install gives error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
" - but that also did not work.
[image]

Could anyone please help why?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install gives error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: You both got the error message `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. Did you try the accepted answer? Using `easy_install` seems fairly easy and might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @fenceop. Yes, I tried and it did not work - please see edited question

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using this link send to me by Nexmo support team: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/