# MS Visual C++ 14.1 is required. But it is already installed

Tags: python, pip, pypy

I am on Windows 10 using pypy3.6-v7.3.0. I am trying to install numpy with `pip install numpy`, but I keep getting the error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/%60)

However, I already have Visual Studio Community 2019 installed, and my C++ build tools are fully up to date.

Here is the new error I am getting after installing build tools manually:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/f3/795e50e3ea2dc7bc9d1a2eeea9997d5dce63b801e08dfc37c2efce341977/numpy-1.18.4.zip
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.exe C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjxmz4c4z:
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.6
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 69, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pt1e0dfd\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pt1e0dfd\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 250, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pt1e0dfd\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 488, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 480, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pt1e0dfd\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 161, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pt1e0dfd\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 146, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 157, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 290, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 380, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 661, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.exe C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjxmz4c4z" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1iwlc8lz\numpy
```

I am no longer seeing the original error anymore, I am always getting this no matter what now. I tried using `pip install numpy`, `pip3 install numpy`, and `pypy -m pip install numpy`. All give this same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If your build tools not answering to your problem, try to install build tools manually through this [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe?fixForIE=.exe).
2. After that you have to restart your PC or laptop.
3. Then try `pip3 install numpy`. In python 3.x versions we use `pip3` not `pip`.

Comment: Thank you. I installed that and restarted. I updated my question with the new output I am getting.

Comment: @chrispytoes for your new problem, follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61563861/11383441)

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear distinctions between certain versions of Visual C++ Build Tools.

- Visual studio version 2015 build tools -> VC 14.0
- Visual studio version 2017 build tools -> VC 14.1
- Visual studio version 2019 build tools -> VC 14.2

Choose the build tools you need from the menu accordingly:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [chocolatey's numpy](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/numpy) package directly:

```
choco install numpy
```

Answer (score -1):

`pip install numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl`

Try installing from wheel package directly.

Comment: I couldn't find that exact package but I downloaded `numpy-1.18.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` and it gave me: `numpy-1.18.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: This didn't work because it is for python 3.5 but you have 3.6 version. Go to https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files from here see which is supported by your python version.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize. I just tried `numpy-1.18.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` and got the same thing though.

Comment: Can you check again python --version. To make sure you are using python3 use pip3 install. otherwise use python -m pip install --user numpy scipy. Scipy automatically installs numpy

Comment: For some reason, trying to run `python` or `python3` just opens the Windows Store for me. But running `python3.8` works. But I have them installed and in the PATH. I was able to successfully install it with `python3.8 -m pip install numpy`, but it is not accessible from `pypy`. I tried using `pypy -m pip install numpy` but that gives the same C++ error.