# Visual Studio Express 2010 / unable to find vcvarsall.bat in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x

So, I'm having the problem of `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` on Python 3.4 on Windows. The solution would be to install Visual Studio Express 2010 [as answered on e.g. [Unable to find vcvarsall.bat using Python 3.3 in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658092/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-using-python-3-3-in-windows-8) ]

My problem is i can't find an install link for this anywhere - at least from Microsoft - most links (including on the answer to the question above) get re-directed to install Visual Studio Express 2015, which presumably won't be suitable.

Does Microsoft still allow downloads of VS-Express 2010 - and if so, where? [i'd ideally prefer to install direct from Microsoft rather than a 3-rda party]

**Follow-up:**  The "easiest solution" for my problem was just to upgrade to Python 3.5, and then use Visual Studio Express 2015

Comment: I think that _Python_ 3.x (except 3.5) is built with [_Visual Studio 20**13**_](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).

Comment: @CristiFati:  see https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows.  "*Python 3.5 and later use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. 
Python 3.3 and 3.4 use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. 
Most Python versions prior to 3.3 use Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.*"

Comment: I know this can be easier said than done, but I seriously suggest you try to move on to 3.5 so you can use VS 2015.

Comment: @cdarke - yep - that was what i just ended up doing - thanks!

Comment: @kyrenia: yes sorry for the confusion.