# First: "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" and Now: "TypeError: unorderable types: NonType() >= str()"

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I am currently in the process of setting up django on a windows machine. So far I have done the following:

- Installed Python 3.3 -> SUCCESS!
- Installed Django -> SUCCESS!
- Installed MySql Database -> SUCCESS!

Yesterday I tried running "`pip install mysql-python`" to get the right module for connecting python to mysql, however I got the error "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat". After some digging on stackoverflow [[this solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip) seems to have fixed the problem and I no longer get the error message. However, now when I try run the same pip command I am still not getting through the mysql module installation successfully. I have screenshotted the errors below (everything above that code had no error lines). Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [a binary install](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). pip or easy_install don't always work on windows for packages like this

Comment: Thanks yuvi, I will do this, however I am stubborn and still want to find a solution to the above :)

Comment: No no! Don't waste your time. I assure you there is none. Seriously, I am closely familiar with the vcvarsall.bat error, I have tried battling it, attempting to use different compilere and even compile some of the packages myself and doing horrible things of the sort but to no avail. On Windows just use a binary install

Comment: Alright, convinced :) Do you know if there is a mysql-python module for Python 3.3? can't seems to find it.

Comment: Currently no, but it's supposedly coming soon (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

Comment: sure thing, happy to have helped =]

Comment: I would have voted this down, if not for lack of rep.  The visual c environment batch file error has a rather simple fix - install Visual C++ Express 2008.  This has worked for me, without fuss, with any cross-platform module (those not calling posix apis).  EDIT: 2010 for python 3.3+

Comment: I'm familiar with that fix as well. Never worked for me. Using mingW as compiler as suggested at the link in the question, which didn't work either. I'm sure what you're saying is true for some packages, but for most cases using a binary installer is the most straight-forward bug-free solution there is