# .PYX file not found (Cython)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

> "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:/Users/Sameer
>   Khanna/Desktop/NPann-dce_wrist-db62618c97ac/ex_process_dce_roiwise.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Sameer
>   Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 209,
>   in load_module
>       inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)   File "C:\Users\Sameer
>   Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186,
>   in build_module
>       reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 100,
>   in pyx_to_dll
>       dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py",
>   line 164, in run
>       _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py",
>   line 172, in build_extensions
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in
>   build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 315, in compile
>       self.initialize()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 208, in
>   initialize
>       vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 81, in
>   _get_vc_env
>       vcvarsall, vcruntime = _find_vcvarsall(plat_spec)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 34, in _find_vcvarsall
>       access=winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Sameer
>   Khanna/Desktop/NPann-dce_wrist-db62618c97ac/ex_process_dce_roiwise.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from compartmentmodels.compartmentmodels import TwoCXModel, TwoCUModel, CompartmentModel, ModifiedTofts   File "C:\Users\Sameer
>   Khanna\Desktop\NPann-dce_wrist-db62618c97ac\compartmentmodels\compartmentmodels.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from . import c_convolution_exp   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 435,
>   in load_module
>       language_level=self.language_level)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 225,
>   in load_module
>       raise exc.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 209,
>   in load_module
>       inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)   File "C:\Users\Sameer
>   Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186,
>   in build_module
>       reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 100,
>   in pyx_to_dll
>       dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py",
>   line 164, in run
>       _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py",
>   line 172, in build_extensions
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in
>   build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 315, in compile
>       self.initialize()   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 208, in
>   initialize
>       vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 81, in
>   _get_vc_env
>       vcvarsall, vcruntime = _find_vcvarsall(plat_spec)   File "C:\Users\Sameer Khanna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py",
>   line 34, in _find_vcvarsall
>       access=winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY ImportError: Building module compartmentmodels.c_convolution_exp failed:
>   ['FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified\n']
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I get the above error message when trying to use pyximport on Windows.
I am also unable to go through the Cython tutorial, being unable to perform the setup.py and pyximport methods.

I downloaded PyCharm and Anaconda 3.5

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the .pyx file location is in your current directory or PYTHONPATH?

E.g., try to create a file `helloworld.pyx` with the following contents:

```
cimport cython
cpdef hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World'
```

save it in the directory from which you started your python interpreter.

and run

```
>>> import pyximport; pyximport.install()
>>> import helloworld
>>> helloworld.hello_world()
'Hello, World'
```

Alternatively, you can save `helloworld.pyx` somewhere else and add this directory to your PYTHONPATH, e.g.,

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/Sebastian/Desktop')
```

Comment: Yes, I even tried adding it to the path in the way that you suggested. Same error: ImportError: Building module hello failed: ['FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified\n']

Comment: Hm, it seems like you have a compiler issue then. Maybe you have installed some stuff via pip rather than conda?

Comment: Ah, before I post a lengthy comment, maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip

Comment: I only installed pycharm and anaconda 3.5

Comment: Are you running this via PyCharm? If yes, please try to run the same code from the command line -- I bet it will work then.

Comment: Finally got past that problem, but now I have another issue. Now I get a TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()\n

Comment: Glad to hear that it finally worked out for you. The "new" issue sounds like you haven't declared your variables correctly

Comment: I running the cython tutorial. Nothing else.

Comment: Maybe you could post this issue with the variable declaration / types as a separate question or update your original question including the actual code you are trying to run