# Python3.5 - error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, windows, lxml

My problem is not new and occurred to others with the same error (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat), while installing 'lxml'. I use Python 3.5 and windows 7. I tried to follow the recommended steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/10558328#10558328) but failed

1. I installed mingw32 to `C:\programs\mingw\`
2. Add mingw32's bin directory to your environment variable: append
   `c:\programs\MinGW\bin;` to the PATH

I went wrong here. May you explain me (simply) how to add mingw32's bin directory to the path?

3. Edit (create if not existing) distutils.cfg file located at C:\Python35\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg to be:

   [build]

   compiler=mingw32

I didn't get this step at all.

4. Now run `pip install lxml`.

I got this one and I made sure the environment was set by opening a new `cmd.exe`.

Any advice to complete these steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is part of a different compiler, namely Microsoft's Visual C++ suite. To verify the path changes, open a terminal (hit Window+R, type cmd) and then run `echo %PATH%`.

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is related to Visual C++ compiler, not to MinGW (gcc). You probably update the wrong file when setting the compiler (`C:\Python26` does not look like a Python 3.5 directory!).

Comment: @Holt I tried to adapt this solution to Python 3.5. I edited the step.

Comment: @emeryville You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618532/2666289), and if does not work, update your question with the new error (if it is new).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I ran `echo %PATH%` and I don't see anything related to MinGW

Comment: @emeryville You could check [that page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) which contains lots of precompiled Windows package for Python 2.7 / 3.4 / 3.5. In particular, you can find [lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) - Simply download `lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win32.whl` (or the 64 bits version) and run `pip install lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win32.whl` (when in the correct folder).

Comment: I'd suggest using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io) on windows. Setting up your env on Windows is a pain in the A.

Comment: @mirosval Thanks. Is anaconda like RStudio for R (for which I am much more familiar!) ?

Comment: @Holt Thanks. I will try.

Comment: @emeryville not really, R Studio is an IDE, while Anaconda is a Python distribution, it will help you manage your Python, install, remove packages and so on, much easier than managing Python yourself. If you want an IDE, look up PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

I think installing mingw32 is not a good idea.
Please follow these setps:

1. check your Python's versions, 3.4 will be easy to install;
2. download the `whl` and use `pip install` command;
3. go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ where you'll find the file as your wish.

Answer (score 1):

I should install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from ...
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266