# Error when Installing simplecrypto on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to install the Python module [simplecrypto](https://simplecrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on a Windows machine. To do this I run the following:

```
C:\Python36\Scripts>pip install simplecrypto
```

However, upon running this partway through the installation process I receive the following error:

```
...
Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\EDM-P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-teqxfnwt\\PyCrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\EDM-P\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nrmsip8r-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\EDM-P\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-teqxfnwt\PyCrypto\
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

An error occurs when it attempts to install [PyCrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/), which is a [requirement](https://github.com/boppreh/simplecrypto/blob/master/requirements.txt) of the package. The [GitHub README](https://github.com/boppreh/simplecrypto/blob/master/README.rst) mentions:

> If the dependency installation fail on Windows, you may want to use a
>   [prebuilt installer.](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) If you wish to compile it I suggest using the
>   Mingw tools as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip/5051281#5051281).

Install it from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) and then compile by

> install MinGW with C++ Compiler option checked add C:\MinGW\bin to
>   your PATH in PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils, create a file distutils.cfg and
>   add these lines:
>
> [`build] compiler=mingw32`