# Gensim on windows: C extension not loaded, training will be slow

Tags: python, pip, gensim

I am trying to use word2vec from gensim but I get this warning on running: 
 - C:\Users\user1PycharmProjects\FirstTest\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:1212: UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial
  warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")
 - C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\FirstTest\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py:743: UserWarning: C extension not loaded, training will be slow. Install a C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.
  "C extension not loaded, training will be slow. "

I installed (& configure path):

- mingw32-gcc-ada-bin
- mingw32-gcc-fortran-bin
- mingw32-gcc-g++-bin
- mingw32-gcc-objc-bin

I sure that I have a compiler (tested with a C script), but I don't know why I can't use the fast version of gensim !!!
I run my script on windows 10 with python3.

Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618532/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw+python+pip

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and this worked for me, I am not using anaconda, I use pure python 3.6 so I install my libraries with pip

1.- pip uninstall gensim

2.- Install TDM GCC x64 https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/

3.- pip install --upgrade gensim

Hope it helps

Comment: This did not help