# When I use pip install proxybroker commands I get `Command errored out with exit status 1`

Tags: python, pip

I get this error when I try to install proxy broker using `pip install proxybroker`.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this? Thanks!

**ERROR :**

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
    -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g6xxyr1w\\maxminddb\\setup.py'"'"';
    __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g6xxyr1w\\maxminddb\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yj7gz1gk\install-record.txt'
    --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\maxminddb'
             cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g6xxyr1w\maxminddb\
        Complete output (24 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-3.8
        creating build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\const.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\decoder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\reader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        copying maxminddb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\maxminddb
        running egg_info
        writing maxminddb.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to maxminddb.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to maxminddb.egg-info\top_level.txt
        reading manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 2: path 'tests/' cannot end with '/'
    
        writing manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        running build_ext
        error: can't compile C/C++ code: unable to load module 'distutils._msvccompiler'
        ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
    -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g6xxyr1w\\maxminddb\\setup.py'"'"';
    __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g6xxyr1w\\maxminddb\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yj7gz1gk\install-record.txt'
    --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\maxminddb' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with loading the `_msvccompiler`. Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip

Comment: @Salma i tried but i sitll get same error