# Undeclared identifier during Clinamen Python package installation

Tags: python, c, package

I'm trying to install the [Clinamen package](https://gitlab.com/Marrigoni/clinamen) from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Clinamen/) using `pip install clinamen` and I get the following errors :

```
clinamen\descriptors\finger_descriptors_c.c(30): error C2065: 'M_PI'ÿ: identificateur non d‚clar‚
clinamen\descriptors\finger_descriptors_c.c(72): error C2065: 'M_PI'ÿ: identificateur non d‚clar‚
clinamen\descriptors\finger_descriptors_c.c(80): error C2065: 'M_PI'ÿ: identificateur non d‚clar‚
```

In the mentionned file, indeed, there is this M_PI variable in lines 30, 72 and 80.

```
double norm = 4*M_PI*na*na*bin_size/volume;
```

My environmet is the following :

python 3.9
IDE : VSCode 1.65.2
Windows 11
pip 22.0.4

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Try `pip install -U clinamen`.

Comment: Else edit finger_descriptors_c.c to add `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` to make `M_PI` visible.

Comment: Lastly what versions of Microsoft Visual C++ compilers are visible to pip.

Comment: Thank you @Gerhard. As finger_descriptors_c.c is a file from the package I don't know how to modify it. I just saw the M_PI in the source file from gitlab
Also, how to check wht is the Microsoft visual C++ compiler is visible to pip. I recently installed the desktop developments for C++ from MS build tools

Comment: I use MinGW. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip) if you want to try . I do not know how to help you with Microsoft visual C++ compiler.

Comment: I downloaded and modified the finger_descriptors_c.c file, with #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES but it didn't work.
I also tried installing and updating MinGW, but the Clinamen installation didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the installation of clinamen working, after talkking to one of the developers.
I installed it through WSL (windows subsystem for linux).

Had to

- install wsl (from windows store on windows 11)
- install ubuntu distribution (again windows store)
- install Remote extension for VSCode
- Finally installed Clinamen in the bash terminal with a simple `pip install clinamen`