# error while trying to install Neopixel plus

Tags: python, terminal, pip, neopixel

Hello I was trying to install the neopixel plus library but i got this error, I tried to understand it but I doesn't totally understand, seams a file is missing  and the name of the file seems to have an encoding error. Sorry for my english (I'm trying my best)
I have done research for a similar problem but i didn't find any,I still continue my research. Have a good day

```
PS C:\Users\couco> pip install neopixel-plus
Collecting neopixel-plus
  Using cached neopixel_plus-1.7-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting rpi-ws281x
  Using cached rpi_ws281x-4.3.4.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel
  Using cached adafruit_circuitpython_neopixel-6.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colr
  Using cached Colr-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-pixelbuf
  Using cached adafruit_circuitpython_pixelbuf-1.1.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Adafruit-Blinka
  Using cached Adafruit_Blinka-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Adafruit-PlatformDetect>=3.13.0
  Using cached Adafruit_PlatformDetect-3.24.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-typing
  Using cached adafruit_circuitpython_typing-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Adafruit-PureIO>=1.1.7
  Using cached Adafruit_PureIO-1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyftdi>=0.40.0
  Using cached pyftdi-0.54.0-py3-none-any.whl (144 kB)
Collecting pyusb!=1.2.0,>=1.0.0
  Using cached pyusb-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting pyserial>=3.0
  Using cached pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice
  Using cached adafruit_circuitpython_busdevice-5.1.9-py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: rpi-ws281x
  Building wheel for rpi-ws281x (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Compiling ws281x library...
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      copying rpi_ws281x\rpi_ws281x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      copying rpi_ws281x\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      running build_ext
      building '_rpi_ws281x' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\lib
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tclib/dma.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\lib/dma.obj
      dma.c
      lib/dma.c(35): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'unistd.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for rpi-ws281x
  Running setup.py clean for rpi-ws281x
Failed to build rpi-ws281x
Installing collected packages: rpi-ws281x, pyserial, colr, pyusb, Adafruit-PureIO, Adafruit-PlatformDetect, pyftdi, adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice, adafruit-circuitpython-typing, Adafruit-Blinka, adafruit-circuitpython-pixelbuf, adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel, neopixel-plus
  Running setup.py install for rpi-ws281x ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for rpi-ws281x did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      Compiling ws281x library...
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      copying rpi_ws281x\rpi_ws281x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      copying rpi_ws281x\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\rpi_ws281x
      running build_ext
      building '_rpi_ws281x' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\lib
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tclib/dma.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\lib/dma.obj
      dma.c
      lib/dma.c(35): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'unistd.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> rpi-ws281x

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Thanks

Comment: See also https://github.com/glowingkitty/NeoPixelPlus/issues/1

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be a similar issue but it isn't resolved. I continue my research but any help still apreciated

Comment: It's the same issue. The `rpi_ws281x` library includes POSIX headers, which are not available in visual C++. It looks like it was not written for windows, but you can try to compile using mingw, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip) as a start how to set it up

Comment: Ok it was a bit too hard for me so I just used Linux